# TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not async iterable

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-asyncio

I've got a simple python3 webscraper which was working synchronously. I wanted to make it asynchronus, so I modified it a bit. But the program does not iterate over an unpacked list `[(,), (,), (,), ...]` even after converting it into converting it into an iterable list using iter(). Says `TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not async iterable`.

Because my code is big, and I'm still learning asynchronous programming I'll put the main parts here with the Error.

My aim was to fetch the links asynchronously to speed up the process. Is there a way to solve this ?

---

Code :

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import os
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream, pipe

myList = []

def get_myList():
    """
    Append values to myList in the format [(,), (,), (,), ...]
    """

async def download(link, title):

    # Download a page
    try:
        page = await req.get(link)
        # Process with BeautifulSoup
        pass
    except:
        pass

async def main():
    get_myList()

    min_iterList = iter(myList[:])

    stream.starmap(min_iterList, download, ordered=True, task_limit=10)

if __name__=="__main__":
    freeze_support()
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```

---

**Error :**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "async_update_code.py", line 253, in <module>
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/asyncio/base_events.py", line 468, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "async_update_code.py", line 207, in main
    stream.starmap(min_iterList, download, ordered=True, task_limit=10)
  File "/home/yahyaa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiostream/core.py", line 273, in init
    assert_async_iterable(args[0])
  File "/home/yahyaa/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/aiostream/aiter_utils.py", line 56, in assert_async_iterable
    f"{type(obj).__name__!r} object is not async iterable")
TypeError: 'list_iterator' object is not async iterable
```

Comment: Apparently stream.starmap expects an [asynchronous iterator](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#asynchronous-iterators-and-async-for), not a regular one (which iter creates).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the issue of attempting to iterate asynchronously over an ordinary iterator (which you resolved), there is the deeper issue that you're not using an async http library.

For example, you cannot `await` the result of `requests.get` because `requests.get()` does not return an asyncio future, but a [`Response`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response). Removing the `await` makes the error go away, but you end up with ordinary synchronous code. To get the speedup of running multiple downloads in parallel, you need to:

- switch from `requests` to an async http library, such as the excellent [`aiohttp`](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp)
- use [`asyncio.gather`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.gather) to await the downloads running in parallel, as shown e.g. [here](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html)

`aiostream` is likely overkill for this purpose - it specifically handles asynchronous iterators. (Asynchronous iterators are iterator-like objects whose `__next__` is called `__anext__` and is a coroutine. A typical use case would be a database API that provides result rows with an async iteraor. They are iterated over with `async for`, but `aiostream` offers a wide range of operators over async iterators, covering creation, transformation, selection, aggregation, and more.)

Comment: Thanks for helping ! I'll try that.

Comment: The problem why I used `aiostream` because it's easy to understand. The `asyncio` guides look a bit more complex. Those Sessions and everything ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. It's good that this website explains it a bit nicely. +1 again.

Comment: I fixed it up, it downloads asynchronously. Problem is, it downloads without order even after specifying `order=True`. BTW i'm still using `aiostream`.
I can't understand how/why to use `async.gather`. It collects results in one list which i don't want to do. I want to process them simultaneously. If there is another good guide, can you recommend one ? 
Also, my modified(working) code here is posted on repl.it  where you can run it online : https://repl.it/@Kogam22/Python-EPUB-Save

Comment: @GoogleUser What you're doing reads like a typical use case for `gather`, which **does** process the coroutines simultaneously, and only returns the list once they're all done for convenience (you can ignore the list if you don't need it).

Comment: I tried with `asyncio.gather` too. No avail. Can you monkey patch my script to work with `gather` ? Post it anywhere like pastebin.com or paste.ee and comment the link here.
Thanks.

Comment: @GoogleUser That seems like it would fit the codereview or softwareengineering stackexchange site. Still, it shouldn't be a problem to figure out `gather`, just follow the examples by Paweł, or others on the net - googling for aiohttp parallel download gives several relevant results.

Comment: Please, as you already know how to, can you do it. I've check many examples but they're not helping me. Even Pawel's example downloads everything without order which is not what I want(I want it to be async + ordered).

Comment: @Kogam22 If you want the downloads to be ordered, then they cannot be parallel, and `gather` will not help you. Also, please note that asking others to write your code for you is outside the scope of StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured how to get it working in order with `aiostream`(the project maintainer helped on github). 
I agree you are correct, but when you are already helping why not just 5 minutes more ?
Thanks again for helping me.

Comment: @Kogam22 Because it's not really five minutes - fixing up or restructuring someone else's code is considerable work. Also, your requirements seem to be in conflict - on the one hand, you want the downloads to run in parallel, and on the other hand, you want to retain the order of downloads. But if `aiostream` helped you, then even better. It's an excellent library.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, you need an asynchronous iterator here. After fixing it, it downloads the urls asynchronnously in order.

After [asking the project maintainer on gihub](https://github.com/vxgmichel/aiostream/issues/26), I understand how it actually works.

```
xs = stream.iterate(myList)
ys = stream.starmap(xs, download, ordered=True, task_limit=20)
zs = stream.starmap(ys, process, ordered=True, task_limit=20)
await ys
```

How does it work ?

- First we create an asynchrosnous iterable object over `myList`.
- Then we pass it `download` which fetches results asynchronously.
- We then pass the downloaded content returned from `download` to `process` function to process it how
  we want to. In my case, with Beautiful Soup 4.

Note that `starmap` accepts unpacked values in the form `[(,), (,), (,), . . .]`. You can squeeze more values inside those tuples. I needed two, so I set them in that format.

---

**The working code :**

```
import asyncio
from aiostream import stream, pipe
from aiohttp import ClientSession
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

myList = []

def get_myList():
    #Append values to myList in the format [(,), (,), (,), ...]
    pass

async def download(link, title):
    # Download a page
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
            response = await response.read()
            return (response, title)

def process(response, title):
    # Do some processing with bs4
    pass

async def main():
    get_myList()

    xs = stream.iterate(myList)
    ys = stream.starmap(xs, download, ordered=True, task_limit=20)
    zs = stream.starmap(ys, process, ordered=True, task_limit=20)
    await ys

if __name__=="__main__":
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()
```